# Installation issue with SDL Tridion 2013 & SDL Web 8 CME not loading all items properly

Tags: 2013, cme, web8

I have upgrade our existing SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 + HR1 environment to SDL Tridion 2013. While validating the new CME I am getting following error continuously in the "Notifications" section

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

The new GUI does not load all the items properly; this could be because of above error but it does loads items when I select "Refresh" option from the context menu. And on the IE browser it is throwing a JavaScript error with the following message:

```
Webpage error details
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; 
            Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729;
           .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Thu, 18 Apr 2013 06:30:23 UTC

Message: Error:

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
Line: 76
Char: 1579
Code: 0
URI: http://sdltridion.abc.com/WebUI/Core/coreresource_v7.0.0.568.8_.js?sav=1&cnt=core*
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This issue occurs when the Web site uses Integrated Authentication and has a name that is mapped to the local loopback address.
Follow the below URL and disable the loopback check

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Comment: Thank You very much Ram Saurabh for providing solution to set "DisableLoopbackCheck" registry entry which helps to  resolve this issue. After creating "DisableLoopbackCheck" registry value we need to restart the computer. FYI we have "Windows Authentication" enabled on the SDL Tridion website and on the host file we have host entry as 127.0.0.1 sdltridion.abc.com .