# Issue installing the Content Porter client

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009

I am getting a freak issue with Content Porter 2009 SP1 in my SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 environment.

I am trying to download the Content Porter from the Content Manager Explorer (from the Tools menu) in Internet Explorer (from the same environment I have downloaded the Content Porter and Template builder a number of times and few months ago). However, this time I am getting the error - "Can not retrieve Application. Authorization error" as shown below:

[image]

The error in the log shows:

```
System.Net.WebException
        - The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
```

Does anyone faced this issue and know the root cause?

**What I have investigated so far:**

- The user with which I am trying to download is a System Admin
- Authentication Mode of SDL Tridion CM and Import Export Service in IIS is set to Anonymous - however, even changing it to Windows Authentication does not work
- Tried downloading on multiple machines including CM Server but all are giving the same error
- On other machines, where Content Porter is already installed, With the same user I can successfully do the export and import - On remote machines as well as on the CM server
- Tried with other browsers (FireFox and Chrome) - They do not give Authorization error but throws "Can not download the application.." error as shown below:
  [image]
- If instead of downloading from the CME, I copy the Content Porter executable from the CM server and install it on machine, it get installed successfully and and allow me to do the Export/Import correctly.

Comment: Do you have LDAP or SSO configured?

Comment: Chrome can be used when you install the [ClickOnce extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clickonce-for-google-chro/eeifaoomkminpbeebjdmdojbhmagnncl?hl=en)

Comment: @ user978511: No LDAP or SSO

@ Bart: Thanks for the information

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be similar to the SDL [HTTP 401.1 error message might occur when accessing Template Builder Custom Page](http://kb.sdl.com/?portalid=23&articleid=3592#tab:homeTab:crumb:7:artId:3592) Knowledgebase article in which it recommends using 'Anonymous Authentication'.

There are a couple things that you could check on top of what you have listed....

1.Check that the 'Client' folder also has just 'Anonymous Authentication' enabled.
[image]

2.If using LDAP, the [online documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_ContentPorter_2013/task_2GDGDH5050KGKLGLKSJNNCVVSFGSDHD) (login required) is quite insistent that **only** 'Anonymous Authentication' enabled for the Client folder, so ensure that this is the case.

> Select the virtual directory called ImportExportService\Client and
>   enable Anonymous Authentication **(and disable all others)**.

3.Make sure that the 'Client' folder itself has the security configured to allow the files to be read by anonymous users

[image]

I assume that you have already [disabled the lookback check](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/937/71) if your Tridion URL is different than your machine name.

**[UPDATE]**
It may also be worth checking that the Tridion CME site is in the correct 'Zone' in Internet Explorer and that the browser is configured correctly, as there are a few [Internet Explorer settings that affect ClickOnce](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/deployment/0321197690/clickonce-security/ch06lev1sec2):

- Script Activation
- Disable ClickOnce MIME Handler
- Disable Managed Code

Comment: Thanks Jon. However, I have already checked that:
(1) Client folder also has Anonymous Authentication enabled (2) No LDAP or SSO is in place 
(3) I need to check this and will update (Need to get this info from the Server Managing company as I do not have direct access to the server)

Comment: Checked All the browser setting mentioned and they are all as expected.

Comment: I doubt if the ImportExportService is involved here. This is called by the Content Porter once it is installed, but probably not involved in downloading the Content Porter click-once executable.

Comment: Never mind my previous comment, I see now that the CP client is inside Content Porter\ImportExportService\Client.