# Issue in WEB 8 with DXA 1.4

Tags: dxa, web8

[image]I am working on DXA 1.4 and WEB 8 while execting the default page getting below error

**CD_client log**

> 2016-04-12 12:45:34 INFO [Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.AutoConfigure.get_ODataV4ServiceEndpoint] - content-service endpoint found from discovery service.

**Site log**

> 2016-04-12 12:45:39,326 [6] ERROR - Service unavailable
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ServiceUnavailableException: Service unavailable ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceTransportException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8083
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>      at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponse()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponse()
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.GetResponseHelper(ODataRequestMessageWrapper request, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean handleWebException)
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.InnerSynchExecute[TElement](Uri requestUri, String httpMethod, Nullable`1 singleResult, OperationParameter[] operationParameters)
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.Execute[TElement](Uri requestUri)
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass21`1.<>c__DisplayClass23.b__20()
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass21`1.<Execute>b__1f()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.AbstractODataService.HandleException(Exception e)
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass21`1.b__1f()
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.PerformRetry[T](Func`1 block, Int32 retryCount)
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.Retry[T](Func`1 block, Int32 retryCount, Boolean locking)
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.DynamicMappingsRetrieverImpl.GetPublicationMapping(String url)
>      at Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.DynamicMappingsRetriever.GetPublicationMapping(String url)
>      at Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdApiLocalizationResolver.ResolveLocalization(Uri url) in C:\New folder\dxa-web-application-dotnet-master (1)\dxa-web-application-dotnet-master\Sdl.Web.Tridion\CdApiLocalizationResolver.cs:line 66
>      at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.GetCurrentLocalization() in C:\New folder\dxa-web-application-dotnet-master (1)\dxa-web-application-dotnet-master\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Configuration\WebRequestContext.cs:line 196
>      at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_Localization() in C:\New folder\dxa-web-application-dotnet-master (1)\dxa-web-application-dotnet-master\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Configuration\WebRequestContext.cs:line 23
>      at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\New folder\dxa-web-application-dotnet-master (1)\dxa-web-application-dotnet-master\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:line 54
>   2016-04-12 12:45:51,946 [8] ERROR - Service unavailable
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ServiceUnavailableException: Service unavailable ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceTransportException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8083
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>      at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponse()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponse()
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.GetResponseHelper(ODataRequestMessageWrapper request, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean handleWebException)
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.InnerSynchExecute[TElement](Uri requestUri, String httpMethod, Nullable`1 singleResult, OperationParameter[] operationParameters)
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.Execute[TElement](Uri requestUri)
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass21`1.<>c__DisplayClass23.b__20()
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass21`1.<Execute>b__1f()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.AbstractODataService.HandleException(Exception e)
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass21`1.b__1f()
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.PerformRetry[T](Func`1 block, Int32 retryCount)
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.Retry[T](Func`1 block, Int32 retryCount, Boolean locking)
>      at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.DynamicMappingsRetrieverImpl.GetPublicationMapping(String url)
>      at Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.DynamicMappingsRetriever.GetPublicationMapping(String url)
>      at Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdApiLocalizationResolver.ResolveLocalization(Uri url) in C:\New folder\dxa-web-application-dotnet-master (1)\dxa-web-application-dotnet-master\Sdl.Web.Tridion\CdApiLocalizationResolver.cs:line 66
>      at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.GetCurrentLocalization() in C:\New folder\dxa-web-application-dotnet-master (1)\dxa-web-application-dotnet-master\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Configuration\WebRequestContext.cs:line 196
>      at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_Localization() in C:\New folder\dxa-web-application-dotnet-master (1)\dxa-web-application-dotnet-master\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Configuration\WebRequestContext.cs:line 23
>      at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\New folder\dxa-web-application-dotnet-master (1)\dxa-web-application-dotnet-master\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:line 54

[image]

Comment: Network challenges apparently: `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8083` - maybe the infamous loopback issue? http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/937/33

Comment: @NunoLinhares i have followed the mentioned step in the link but no luck still getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

The error about CdApiLocalizationResolver which could not be resolved is remarkable.
The CdApiLocalizationResolver is introduced in DXA 1.3 and only used if you install DXA 1.3+ for SDL Web 8; in the DXA Provider for 2013 SP1 this class does not exist and CdConfigLocalizationResolver is used instead.
If you get that error, something seems to be wrong with your DXA Web App deployment/configuration.

Are you maybe using the DXA Provider for 2013 SP1 (Sdl.Web.Tridion - check the file properties)?

How did you deploy the DXA Web App?

Comment: Hi Rick

i have downloaded the DXA code from https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet
and the provider dll is DD4T.Providers.SDLWeb8.CIL i have also attached the property of Sdl.Web.Tridion

Please let me know if i missed anything in order to implement DXA 1.4 with WEB 8 or is there any link to implement DXA1.4 with WEB 8 which i can follow

Comment: Ok, so you did a custom build. That should work fine, but you could first try regular DXA deployment using web-install.ps1 (see docs).

Comment: For clarity: you should download the DXA release package from Releases or SDL Community Site (see README.md).

Answer (score 1):

Could you please check the MSDTC settings on the DB server and CD server.
Looks like remote connection could not be established between the servers.
Also check that port 8083 is enabled in firewall, if any.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Sumit 
i have checked MSDTC settings and it was missing from DB server post re-configured the settings error is changes now 

**The type name or alias CdApiLocalizationResolver could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.** attached is the screen shot