# Could not find Content Manager Server 'http://localhost:80'

Tags: content-porter, sites-9.6

We are upgraded CMS 9.6 with Access Management. While we connecting to Content Porter, its connecting to localhost on Browser and provided the required login details, its able to login and coming back to content porter and showing Error like "Could not find Content Manager Server http://localhost:80.

in IIS, we have verified its having *:80 binding for Content manager server. Can you please help me how to fix?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried from a different machine, not locally on the server?

Comment: Please also check if this applies: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/937/33

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the CM server to login to CME with SAML authentication while logging into Content Porter is windows authentication.

Content Porter cannot connect using SAML authentication in Sites 9.x yet...but as said, you can configure content porter to login with Windows authentication.

To do that, ensure the following:

1. in IIS, below Tridion website, look for webservices application, ensure it has Anonymous and Windows authentication enabled.
2. in %TRIDION_HOME%\webservices\web.config, ensure the settings look similar to the below...

-->
          
          
        
        
          
          
            
            
          
        
        
          
          
             -->
          
          
        
      
      
        
          
          
          
            
          
          
          
            
           -->
          
          
          
            
          
          -->

3. That's it.  When Content Porter prompts for credential, ensure to supply a user account that is either belong to the windows machine or domain account, not the user account that you use for logging into CME via Saml authentication.

Answer (score 1):

As of Sites 9.6, you can also configure the CM Server to use "Access Management" authentication for desktop clients like Content Porter.

Technically speaking, this means that the (SOAP) Web Services used by those desktop clients accept OAuth 2.0 bearer tokens (obtained from Access Management). Furthermore, they expose an additional endpoint which reveals the Access Management URL to the client.

You can check whether your CM has been properly configured by accessing these endpoints in your browser.  For example: `<YourCMBaseURL>/webservices/access-management-url`. This should return a plain text response with the Access Management URL.

This, in turn, triggers the desktop client to start a user authentication flow in a browser and thus obtain a user Access Token. The user Access Token is then included as OAuth bearer token in all subsequent request for the Web Service.